# Recommended NFS mount options for automount maps?

Tags: nfs, automount

I am considering what NFS mounting options should be used in a large collection of automount maps being used over a large number of hosts (>500).  Of note, there is a collection of machines, both Linux (RH, Suse) and UNIX (Sun, AIX, HP/UX). Also, there is automount support provided for hosts outside the US.  What I have been considering is the following options in the maps:

```
 intr,bg,soft,retry=10,timeo=600,retrans=10
```

I have not specified rsize or wsize as I understand that the largest size between the host and the server is negotiated.

What do you all use or recommend?

Comment: Why are you considering rh change ? What is broken ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can't specify more for autofs then any regular NFS mounts all the caution regarding NFS applies. The rsize and wsize parameters have non-maximum defaults but will be negotiated when you set it to something very large and you have to check `/proc/mounts`to see what was negotiated. Generally your settings seem fine to me as a NFS service interruption taken care of in your case due to the `intr,bg,timeo` et al.

Do I understand that correctly, you mount NFS via a WAN?